# Xcode duplicates my repository and renames its location to lowercase

Tags: xcode, git, repository

I have a Git repository where my project is linked to. It is located somewhere like `/Users/a/Documents/Xcode Projects/MyProject`. I use Xcode's UI to commit changes and it worked perfectly for a couple of times. But now, out of a sudden, I get this error when trying to commit new changes:

> The working copy `myproject` could not be reached.
>   Please verify that the working copy is reachable and try again.

As you can see, the message shows my project's name in **lowercase** and when I check the Repositories in XCode (File - Source Control - Repositories...). I see there are two, apparently identical, repositories (they both link to the same **Origin**), but one with the name all in lowercase.

The correct one location is `/Users/a/Documents/Xcode Projects/MyProject` as I told you. But the duplicated one is supposed to be located in `/Users/a/Documents/xcode projects/myproject` which, of course, does not exist.

Does anybody know why is this happening? Can anybody help me to delete this duplicated repository and make my project link the correct one? So I can keep using the XCode's UI to commit changes in my code.

Comment: I am using XCode 4.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Xcode 4.2 can behave in two different ways depending on what exactly you select in the File->Open dialog, when opening the project from within Xcode:

1. The .xcodeproj file
2. The project folder (containing the .xcodeproj file)

Selecting 1 or 2 and pressing enter wil give me two different repositories with different paths in Xcode's Repositories, so sometimes it helps to close the project, delete both repositories and then open the project in "the right way", say 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I do not really think this is a good solution, since it will mean loosing the repo history... but it helps to stop having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You probably clicked the recent opened project offered at the beginning of Xcode screen. I chose to open the project/workspace from manual selection in the file system and it solved this duplicated working copy issue. Hope it could be a help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why do you think this is not a solution? This is some bug from Xcode and I pointed out a certain way to get around that bug. I can also point out how to change the commit file to get rid of the duplicated copy but who cares if there is an easier solution?