# Xcode/Git Repository Error: "Please verify that the working copy is reachable and try again."

Tags: xcode, git, bitbucket

Here are the steps I take.

1. I open Xcode (4.3.3) organizer and select *Checkout or Clone Repository*
2. I choose the location https://MyUsername@bitbucket.org/MyUsername/myrepo.git
3. Press *Clone* button and it successfully clones it on my local disk
4. So I open the local copy of the project and perform some changes to it.
5. When I try to commit changes (or do any other git related operation) I get the following error:

> **The working copy "MyAppName" could not be reached.**
>
> *Please verify that the working copy is reachable and try again.*

However I can perform commits (and other types of git operations) without any issues from the Terminal app using command lines.

I've tried restarting my computer, deleting all Xcode settings, but nothing helped.

**Update**: I tried it again today and it works fine now. Maybe it's some sort of an intermittent bug in Xcode.

Comment: So the case of the name of your project didn't change? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673366/xcode-duplicates-my-repository-and-renames-its-location-with-lowercase)

Comment: I'v tried all the answers, no one worked for me, any idea? You guys get it works?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever this happens to me (and it happens often) I do the following:

1-Close the project
2-Open the organiser
3-Go into the repositories tab.

If your current working copy has been added to the list already, then within the organizer navigate to it, and double-click on the .xcodeproj project.
This will re-open the project in XCode, and you'll find that now SCM operation will work fine.

If your current working copy hasn't been added to the list, press the + button in the bottom left corner, select "Add Working Copy", navigate to the folder containing the .xcodeproj and open this folder.

Now double click on the .xcodeproj file, the project will open in XCode.

And it's all working fine again...

No idea why this make things work... but it does

Comment: Haven't experienced the issue since I posted the question. But I'll give your method a try when I do. cheers

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. It happens if you have ~/ in the path to project. Works fine, when you open your project from organizer.

Comment: Even I open the project from organizer, it will create a same project in repositories with ~/xxx/xxx, and the item is RED.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug of Xcode! When you search the xxx.xcodeproj from your Home folder of the dialog box  directly, Xcode will use the `~/xxx/xxx` as the SVN/Git path which is completely wrong.

So you should avoid this, and search from the "/" path instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer you might be looking for, but I ran across similar problems when using Remote git repository (Github) and Xcode.

I ended up using a GUI tool "SourceTree", a good and easy to use tool to pull/push your code from Local Git to Remote Git Repository. Try it out http://sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: I have the SourceTree app installed as well, but that's really a back up plan for me. I would really like to use Xcode, it has some great SCM features. Also, the fact that source control is integrated into the IDE makes a better workflow.